# BinaryTreeLUT , tree deletion

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have the following binary search tree as below, and am trying to delete a node using the method illustrated in this wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion

The main idea is to modify lrMerge (method in below code) when both subtrees are present. Then the node to be deleted is replaced by the rightmost node in the left tree (which itself is deleted). There is a test file at the end of the code below. I tried to change IrMerge to be like the wiki deletion code - but have not been succesful.

```
class KeyNotFoundInTableException extends Exception {
}



public class BinaryTreeLUT {

/**
 * The member class Key is used for the indexing keys of the LUT. It
 * is a String with basic comparative methods added.
 */
protected class Key {

    public Key(String s) {
        kString = s;
    }

    public boolean equals(Key k) {
        return kString.equals(k.toString());
    }

    public boolean lessThan(Key k) {
        return (kString.compareTo(k.toString()) < 0);
    }

    public boolean greaterThan(Key k) {
        return (kString.compareTo(k.toString()) > 0);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return kString;
    }

    private String kString;
}

/**
 * The member class Entry encapsulates an entry of the LUT and contains
 * a {key, value} pair.
 */
protected class Entry {

    public Entry(Key k, Object v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

    protected Key key;
    protected Object value;
}

/**
 * The member class BSTreeNode encapsulates node of the binary search
 * tree, which contains a LUT entry and links to left and right 
 * subtrees.
 */
protected class BSTreeNode {

    public BSTreeNode(Entry e) {
        kvPair = e;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public BSTreeNode(Entry e, BSTreeNode l, BSTreeNode r) {
        kvPair = e;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    protected Entry kvPair;
    protected BSTreeNode left;
    protected BSTreeNode right;
}

//Single protected data member - the LUT is stored in a sequence.
protected BSTreeNode root;

/**
 * Default constructor - no need to specify capacity of LUT.
 */
public BinaryTreeLUT() {
    root = null;
}

/**
 * Inserts a new key-value pair into the look-up table.
 */
public void insert(String key, Object value) {

    BSTreeNode newNode = new BSTreeNode(new Entry(new Key(key), value));
    addToTree(newNode, root);
}

/**
 * Removes the key-value pair with the specified key from the look-up 
 * table.
 */
public void remove(String key) throws KeyNotFoundInTableException {

    Key searchKey = new Key(key);
    removeFromTree(searchKey, root);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the key-value pair with the specified key from the look-up 
 * table.
 */
public Object retrieve(String key) throws KeyNotFoundInTableException {

    Key searchKey = new Key(key);
    BSTreeNode treeNode = getFromTree(searchKey, root);
    return treeNode.kvPair.value;
}

/**
 * Updates the key-value pair with the specified key with the new 
 * specified value.
 */
public void update(String key, Object value) throws KeyNotFoundInTableException {

    Key searchKey = new Key(key);
    BSTreeNode treeNode = getFromTree(searchKey, root);
    treeNode.kvPair.value = value;
}

/**
 * Returns a string listing all the key-entry pairs in the LUT
 */
public String toString() {
    return treeString(root);
}

//protected methods implementing recursive operations on the tree.

/**
 * Adds newNode to the tree rooted at curNode recursively.
 */
protected void addToTree(BSTreeNode newNode, BSTreeNode curNode) {

    //Special case for empty tree.
    if(curNode == null) {
        root = newNode;
    }

    //General case: recurse left or right depending on comparison.
    else if(curNode.kvPair.key.lessThan(newNode.kvPair.key)) {
        if(curNode.left == null) {
            curNode.left = newNode;
        }
        else {
            addToTree(newNode, curNode.left);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(curNode.right == null) {
            curNode.right = newNode;
        }
        else {
            addToTree(newNode, curNode.right);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the node containing k from the tree rooted at node.
 */
protected BSTreeNode getFromTree(Key k, BSTreeNode node) throws        KeyNotFoundInTableException {

    if(node == null) {
        throw new KeyNotFoundInTableException();
    }
    else if(node.kvPair.key.equals(k)) {
        return node;
    }
    else if(node.kvPair.key.lessThan(k)) {
        return getFromTree(k, node.left);
    }
    else {
        return getFromTree(k, node.right);
    }
}

/**
 * Removes the node containing k from the tree rooted at node.
 */
protected void removeFromTree(Key k, BSTreeNode node) throws KeyNotFoundInTableException {
    //Special case for empty tree.
    if(node == null) {
        throw new KeyNotFoundInTableException();
    }

    //Special case when deleting the root node.
    else if(root.kvPair.key.equals(k)) {
        root = lrMerge(root);
    }

    //If the key at the current node is less than 
    //the search key, go to the left subtree.
    else if(node.kvPair.key.lessThan(k)) {

        //If the left subtree is empty, the tree cannot contain
        //the search key.

        if(node.left == null) {
            throw new KeyNotFoundInTableException();
        }

        //If this is the parent of the node to be removed, do
        //the removal.
        if(node.left.kvPair.key.equals(k)) {
            node.left = lrMerge(node.left);
        }

        //Otherwise, recurse down another level.
        else {
            removeFromTree(k, node.left);
        }
    }

    //Otherwise go to the right subtree.
    else {

        //If the right subtree is empty, the tree cannot contain
        //the search key.

        if(node.right == null) {
            throw new KeyNotFoundInTableException();
        }

        //If this is the parent of the node to be removed, do
        //the removal.
        if(node.right.kvPair.key.equals(k)) {
            node.right = lrMerge(node.right);
        }

        //Otherwise, recurse down another level.
        else {
            removeFromTree(k, node.right);
        }
    }
}   

/**
 * Merges the two subtrees of node prior to removal of
 * the node from the tree.
 */
protected BSTreeNode lrMerge(BSTreeNode node) {

    BSTreeNode mergedTrees = null;

    //First two cases occur when one or both
    //subtrees of the node to be deleted are empty.
    if(node.left == null) {
        mergedTrees = node.right;
    }
    else if(node.right == null) {
        mergedTrees = node.left;
    }

    //Otherwise, merge the left and right subtrees
    //and link the merged structure to the current
    //node. 
    else {
        addToTree(node.right, node.left);
        mergedTrees = node.left;
    }

    return mergedTrees;
}

/**
 * Uses in order tree traversal to construct a string containing all the
 * key value pairs in the binary search tree.
 */
protected String treeString(BSTreeNode node) {
    if(node == null) {
        return "";
    }

    Entry lutEntry = node.kvPair;
    String thisNode = "";
    thisNode = lutEntry.key.toString();
    thisNode += ":";
    thisNode += lutEntry.value;
    thisNode += ", ";

    return treeString(node.left) + treeString(node.right) + thisNode;
}
}
```

The test file is here:

BinaryTreeLUTTest.java:

```
public class BinaryTreeLUTTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
BinaryTreeLUT myLUT = new BinaryTreeLUT();

  myLUT.insert("Priscilla", new Integer(41));
  myLUT.insert("Travis", new Integer(34));
  myLUT.insert("Samuel", new Integer(28));
  myLUT.insert("Helena", new Integer(39));
  myLUT.insert("Andrew", new Integer(14));
  myLUT.insert("Kay", new Integer(24));
  myLUT.insert("John", new Integer(67));
  System.out.println(myLUT);

  myLUT.remove("Helena");
  System.out.println(myLUT);

  myLUT.remove("John");
  System.out.println(myLUT);

  myLUT.remove("Travis");
  System.out.println(myLUT);

  myLUT.remove("Samuel");
  System.out.println(myLUT);

  myLUT.remove("Andrew");
  System.out.println(myLUT);

     } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your **entire** implementation, as most of the code doesn't have a whole lot to do with the question. Rather construct a [**Minimal**, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you should describe the problem you're having (by, for example, giving the actual versus expected output for the given code, or a complete stack trace with an indication of line number if you get an exception). Also, you should preferably debug your code to find, or at least narrow down, the issue.